# Inserting to an AS400 table a string containing a mixture of English and Greek characters from C#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, unicode, ibm-midrange

I am trying to insert a new record into my AS400 table with a string value of a mix of Greek and English characters.

**Table structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE RAVONLIBT.LAMBDA ( 
CHRCCS875 CHAR(5) CCSID 875 DEFAULT NULL , 
VARCCS875 VARCHAR(5) CCSID 875 DEFAULT NULL )
```

**C# code:**

```
private void Retrieve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.AppendFormat("SELECT * FROM LAMBDA");

        OdbcConnection con = GetConnection(AS400Library.RAVONLIBT, Resources.Username, Resources.Password);
        DataTable dt = Retrieve(con, sql.ToString());

        textBox1.Text = dt.Rows[0]["CHRCCS875"].ToString();
        textBox2.Text = dt.Rows[0]["VARCCS875"].ToString();
    }
    private void Insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.AppendFormat("INSERT INTO LAMBDA (CHRCCS875,VARCCS875) VALUES ('{0}','{1}'", textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);

        OdbcConnection con = GetConnection(AS400Library.RAVONLIBT, Resources.Username, Resources.Password);
        ExecuteNonQuery(con, sql.ToString());
    }
    private OdbcConnection GetConnection(AS400Library library, string userName, string password)
    {
        return new OdbcConnection(string.Format("ODBC;DATABASE=QGPL;DSN=AS400-{0};UID={1};PWD={2};ALLOWUNSCHAR=0;", library.ToString(), userName, password));
    }
    private int ExecuteNonQuery(OdbcConnection connection, string sql)
    {

        try
        {
            var command = new OdbcCommand(sql);
            command.Connection = connection;
            connection.Open();

            return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
    private DataTable Retrieve(OdbcConnection connection, string sql)
    {
        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(sql);
        command.Connection = connection;
        OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(command);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }

        return dataTable;
    }
```

**AS400 Table records**
[image]

The same string was inserted into the 2 fields in each record. The value for the first record was inserted by copy & paste and the value of the second record using my C# application.

I experimented the following:

1. Read the values from the database from the first record where lambda is readable. I have stored those values in textbox1 and textbox2. I could see the lambda very well.

[image]

2. I have added a new record to the database using the values appearing in textbox1 and texbox2 (from the first step) and I saw that the values are not properly saved (look at the second record).

[image]

And obviously, retrieving the second record to textbox1 and textbox2 do not display the lambda correctly.

And my question is: how can I save a mixture of Greek and English characters in an AS400 table using C# application. 
Do I need to define the columns in the table in a certain format?
Do I need to use a different provider to save to the database?
Do I need to detect the lambda character from my C# application and save it into the database in a different way?

Comment: Apparently CCSID 875 is sufficient to hold the characters you want because they are there in the first row. I am wondering about the ODBC connection, and it's character set. Also what character set is your windows application using? The issue is probably the conversion between the application character set, and CCSID 875 that is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to store a mixture of languages would be in a unicode column.

Assuming a recent release of IBM i use `NATIONAL CHARACTER` types

```
CREATE TABLE RAVONLIBT.LAMBDA ( 
    CHRCCS875 NCHAR(5) DEFAULT NULL , 
    VARCCS875 NVARCHAR(5) DEFAULT NULL )
```

On an older release you can explicitly set use `GRAPHIC` type and `CCSID 1200`

```
CREATE TABLE RAVONLIBT.LAMBDA ( 
   CHRCCS875 GRAPHIC(5) CCSID 1200 DEFAULT NULL , 
   VARCCS875 VARGRAPIC(5) CCSID 1200 DEFAULT NULL )
```

With either method, you get the same results, a UTF-16 column.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, as @jmarkmurphy said, CCSID 875 is sufficient to hold greek characters.
In order to make it works via the code, it is needed to add to the connection string the following:

```
 UNICODESQL=1
```

You can find additional information at [IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_i5_54/rzaik/rzaikconnstrkeywordstranprop.htm)

Using ODBC Connection, the connection string is:

```
private OdbcConnection GetConnection(AS400Library library, string userName, string password)
{
    return new OdbcConnection(string.Format("ODBC;DATABASE=QGPL;DSN=AS400-{0};UID={1};PWD={2};ALLOWUNSCHAR=0;UNICODESQL=1;", library.ToString(), userName, password));
}
```